# FileExtension filter in ListBox

Tags: vb.net

so here is my small code for one button to add items to my listbox.

```
 FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    FilePathLabel.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
    Dim folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
    Dim arrfile() As IO.FileInfo
    Dim file As IO.FileInfo
    arrfile = folder.GetFiles("*.*")
    dicPaths.Clear()
    For Each file In arrfile
        'ListBox1.Items.Add(file.FullName)
        dicPaths.Add(file.Name, file.FullName)
    Next file
    For Each item As String In dicPaths.Keys
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next item
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        FindFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
    End If

    Label1.Text = "Total Items : " + ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString
```

My question is, how to filter all files with extension other than for example .mp3 and .mp4 ? I dont want to have files with extensions like .ink or .exe . I assume it is the line

```
arrfile = folder.GetFiles("*.*")
```

But I tried to write either *.mp3 etc but It didnt work. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: if you have multiple file types you want to add, you could evaluate `file.Extension` in your `For Each file` loop.  I suspect the reason it didnt work is the "etc" in `I tried to write either *.mp3 etc`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the extensions you are interested in in an array and use an outer loop to check each extension.

```
FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
FilePathLabel.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
Dim folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
dicPaths.Clear()

'New code to search for multiple extensions
Dim exts() As String = {"*.mp3", "*.mp4"}
For Each ext As String In exts
    For Each myFile As IO.FileInfo In folder.GetFiles(ext)
        dicPaths.Add(myFile.Name, myFile.FullName)
    Next 
Next

For Each item As String In dicPaths.Keys
    ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
Next item
If CheckBox2.Checked Then
    FindFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
End If

Label1.Text = "Total Items : " + ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to filter the files you are interested in:

```
Dim extensions() As String = { ".mp3", ".mp4" }
Dim arrfile() As FileInfo = (
    From fileInfo In folder.EnumerateFiles()
    Where extensions.Contains(fileInfo.Extension)
).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

[GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx) supports `*` **and** `?`, so you could simply do:

```
arrfile = folder.GetFiles("*.mp?")
```

Side note: Just add the FileInfo instances directly to your ListBox via DataSource, then set the DisplayMember and ValueMember values:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        Dim files As New List(Of IO.FileInfo)(folder.GetFiles("*.mp?"))
        ListBox1.DataSource = files
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FullName"

        If CheckBox2.Checked Then
            FindFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        End If

        FilePathLabel.Text = "Total Items : " + ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblFullname.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
    Dim fi As IO.FileInfo = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    ' ... possibly do something with "fi" ...
    Debug.Print(fi.FullName)
End Sub
```

So now you have access to the actual FileInfo instance that represents the currently selected item.  You can do whatever you want with it...